# Applying a QTip to Multiple JQueryUI Sliders

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, qtip2

Here is [how to apply a QTip to a JQueryUI slider and display its value](http://jsfiddle.net/craga89/w6pnE/).

```
var slider = $('#jqueryui-slider').slider({
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        handle.qtip('option', 'content.text', '' + ui.value);
    }
}),
    handle = $('.ui-slider-handle', slider);

handle.qtip({
    id: 'uislider',
    content: '' + slider.slider('option', 'value'),
    position: {
        my: 'bottom center',
        at: 'top center',
        container: handle 
    },
    hide: {
        delay: 1000
    },
    style: {
        widget: true
    }
});
```

I'm trying to figure out how to apply multiple QTips in the same fashion (where the value of the slider is displayed in the tip), but for any number of sliders on the same page.

I need this because I'm dynamically creating sliders on a page, and the number of sliders will vary from record to record.

**EDIT**

To clarify a bit further, because I'm dynamically generating the sliders on the page, one-by-one, they are currently being configured independently and each requires its own parameters (max, value, step) and slide-action event.

Because of the need to be independently initialized (and the need to reference varying html elements in the slide() event) multiple .slider() are currently being used.  Here is an example of one .slider() that may be added to a page (using ASP.net, with controls dynamically generated within a repeater).  It uses hidden fields to initialize the slider based on the type of value being manipulated.  Also, it updates labels and other values (also dynamically generated) on the page inside the slide() event.

The current answer shows how to configure multiple sliders, but uses only one slider() declaration.  I'm really looking for an answer that does the same thing but **allows for each slider to be independently configured**.  If this can still be accomplished with one slider() call then that will work too, although I'm not sure if this can be done.

```
var currentSlider = $('#<%=panSlider.ClientID%>').slider({
        range: "min",
        max: parseInt($('#<%=hfMaxValue.ClientID%>').val()),
        value: parseInt($('#<%=hfInitValue.ClientID%>').val()),
        step: parseInt($('#<%=hfStepValue.ClientID%>').val()),
        slide: function (event, ui) {
          // set the text to show the current value and update the hidden field for postback
          $("#<%=labValue.ClientID%>").text(ui.value);
          $("#<%=hfValue.ClientID%>").val(ui.value);
          // determine the difference from base to current value
          var difference = ui.value - $('#<%=hfBaseValue.ClientID%>').val();
          $("#<%=labDifference.ClientID%>").text(difference);

          // add tooltip to handle

          handle.qtip('option', 'content.text', '' + ui.value);
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jquery's .each funciton to iterate through all the sliders and initialize them serparately.

```
$('.jqueryui-slider').each(function(){
    var slider = $(this).slider({
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            handle.qtip('option', 'content.text', '' + ui.value);
        }
    }),
    handle = $('.ui-slider-handle', slider);

    handle.qtip({
        id: 'uislider',
        content: '' + slider.slider('option', 'value'),
        position: {
            my: 'bottom center',
            at: 'top center',
            container: handle 
        },
        hide: {
            delay: 1000
        },
        style: {
            widget: true
        }
    });    
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dodcbzdw/2/)

Comment: Another problem I'm having is that the slide() event you've created is overriding the slide() event that I defined when I created the slider (which had additional code).  Any way to make it so that the slide() event here is executed but doesn't override my other slide() event code?

Comment: @bperniciaro Can you create a fiddle that demonstrates the issue?  I would say you should implement all the slide functionality you want into the one function.  But a fiddle would be helpful to better understand and give you a concrete solution.

Comment: I generate each slider dynamically (ASP.net) so I don't initially know how any will be on a page. Each slider's HTML, hidden fields to init & store the slider's value, and JQuery to create the slider are part of a single module (specifically an ASP.net user control). 1 or more user controls can be added to a page.  If all sliders/tips are created in a single function, how can I initialize and store the current value of each slider independently?  Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dodcbzdw/8/) with how a page with 3 sliders might appear, with my current approach commented-out.

Comment: The initial slider values in the aforementioned JsFiddle are based on database values, which will also contain other initialization data such as min, max, & step value.  However, I simplified it for the purpose of illustrating the point.  Currently each JQuery .slider() initialization is generated as part of each module.  If this can be moved to a single function which would also allow for independent initialization & value storage then that would be great.

Comment: @bperniciaro here is an example that sets the slider initial and slider fields based each slider.  You mentioned some other properties such as max, min, and step value.. I'm not sure how that information is displayed but you should be able to do something similar to set those values as well.  Let me know if you have any more questions or trouble.  http://jsfiddle.net/dodcbzdw/9/  I am not aware of a way to initialize the sliders twice without overwriting the previous slider.

Comment: Awesome @Trevor that's **exactly** what I was looking for!  I can pass into each module a counter and use that to name the elements accordingly, then the JQuery work operate based on that counter.   Thanks for helping me get over this hurdle!

Answer (score 2):

Look at my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dodcbzdw/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="jqueryui-slider"></div>
<div class="jqueryui-slider"></div>
<div class="jqueryui-slider"></div>
```

JS:

```
var slider = $('.jqueryui-slider').slider({
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        handle.qtip('option', 'content.text', '' + ui.value);
    }
})
```

Not looking at the z-index problems of the tips, this should be what you wanted.
Just use the same class for every slider and use this class to generate all sliders and qtips at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please see edited question for a caveat I didn't initially make clear.

Comment: One bug with the fiddle: if you move the first slider, then hover over a different handle, the value from the previous slider is initially displayed. I'd like for each tip to work independently, so all tips could be displayed together and each show their relative value.